# Java Implementing htonl

Tags: java, io, endianness

I am communicating with a server, each message sent to the server has to be padded with the length of the message,

```
unsigned int len = htonl(msg.size());
```

In C running the length through `htonl` and padding the message works, in Java AFAIK byte order is already in network order so I assumed all I have to do is write the string length before the message to the stream, but this does not work am I missing something?

```
stream.write(msg.length());
stream.write(msg.getBytes());
```

Stream is an `OutputStream`.

Comment: Can you add code of your implementation so far? At the moment I have no idea what is wrong, your description contains not enough information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with your implementation is, that the write-method writes only one byte, see the [documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write%28int%29). The important sentence here is: 'The 24 high-order bits of b are ignored.' So `stream.write(msg.length());` probably doesn't do what is intended. (I assume msg.length() returns an int, correct me if I'm wrong here.)

Try to write the four bytes of an int:

```
stream.write(msg.length() % 256);
stream.write((msg.length() / 256) % 256);
stream.write((msg.length() / (256 * 256)) % 256);
stream.write((msg.length() / (256 * 256 * 256)) % 256);
```

That writes the least significant byte first, you can change the order if wished. You can do the converting to bytes also with bit-shifting, division looks more understandable for me, but that is a question of personal taste.

Comment: `& 0xFF` and `>> 8` would be more fitting here than % 256` and `/ 256`, because they more precisely show the intent. But then again a `DataOutputStream` already does that for you: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeInt%28int%29

Comment: Good hint with the DataOutputStream. That should do the things wished much smoother.

Answer (score 21):

```
int htonl(int value) {
  return ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(value)
    .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).getInt(0);
}
```

Alternatively

```
int htonl(int value) {
  if (ByteOrder.nativeOrder().equals(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN) {
     return value;
  }
  return Integer.reverseBytes(value);
}
```

Comment: How does this not have more upvotes?  Clearest answer!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the method [Int.reverseBytes()](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#reverseBytes%28int%29), which on platforms such as x86 will get jitted to the x86's [bswapl](http://jsimlo.sk/docs/cpu/index.php/bswap.html) opcode.

You could condition this off the result of *System.getProperty("sun.cpu.endian")*

Answer (score 0):

And `int` has no specified byte ordering at runtime in the Java platform, simply because there is no way to directly observe the bit pattern representing any value. **However** methods that somehow convert `int` (or other) values to `byte[]` have a defined conversion.

So the correct transmission/reception of that value depends on the correct encoding/decoding to/from `byte[]`. As long as you don't tell us how you do that step, we can't help you do it correctly.